# Sudo <any command> throws: Command not found but works without sudo

Tags: ruby, centos

I'm on a CentOS VPS and using RVM and Capistrano to deploy. for some deployments I need to use sudo, but when I deploy with something like:

```
desc "Restart the application services"
task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "#{sudo} cd #{current_path} && bundle exec foreman export upstart"
end
```

I get: `sudo: bundle: command not found`. that happens even if I run it manually through SSH. I run all of this under a non root user with sudo privileges and root group.

My sudoers file is like:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

root    ALL=(ALL)    ALL
deploy  ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

I tried changing `secure_path` to:

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin`

Doing that makes the `bundle exec` part work but now it says `sudo: cd: command not found`

I'm not sure what to do at this point, any one knows why?

Comment: What does `which sudo` get you on the machine, both in the working and non-working states?  It sounds like your `sudo` might be in a weird place.

Comment: it's `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Er, actually, I misread the problem.  `sudo` is found; it's `bundle` that's missing.  Make sure you have Bundler installed on the machine.

Comment: @Jim i think you misunderstood the issue, Bundler is installed as quoted: `Doing that makes the bundle exec part work`

Answer (score 0):

`cd` isn't an executable; it's a shell built-in, thus the `cd: command not found`.  You're also not quoting your full `sudo` command, so `sudo` is only running the part before the `&&`.  Try this:

```
desc "Restart the application services"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "#{sudo} sh -c 'cd #{current_path} && bundle exec foreman export upstart'"
  end
end
```

You can replace `sh` with whatever shell you prefer, or use `$SHELL` if it's set.